# Why does this call to my controller not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following JavaScript code on my view in MVC4 project:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/Object/GetMyObjects/",
    data: {
        __RequestVerificationToken: jQuery("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val(),
    },
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true
}).success(function (data) {
    sfds = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

and the following method in `ObjectController`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult GetMyObjects()
{
    var sfds= _db.SFDS.ToList();
    return View(sfds);
}
```

Why does the controller not get called when the JavaScript is run? Even when I remove the ValidateAntiForgereToken it does not work. In my console I see data returned is null.

I'm having a hard time getting some JSON on my view today.

Comment: here you can find an example of creating an ajax request, and returning a JsonResult: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803565/mvc-3-razor-access-viewdata-in-ajax-request-jquery-javascript/13803842#13803842

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning JSon. You are returning (or attempting to return) a view. You need something like this, in your controller:

return Json(sfds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

And, add this to your .ajax() properties:

dataType: "json",

Comment: Thanks Ill check it out when I'm back inside.

Comment: Sounded very plausible, and thanks, but it still doesn't work. The controller is not called.

Comment: I added code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803565/mvc-3-razor-access-viewdata-in-ajax-request-jquery-javascript/13803842#13803842) and it says: "statusCode: {
                404: function (content) { alert('cannot find resource'); },"